# How to generate multiple tar.gz file by overriding specific files for each environment?

Tags: linux, bash, files

I have a root folder `Products` and then bunch of sub-folders inside it. Each of those sub-folder has bunch of files as of now. Just for simplicity I came up with sub-folders name as `folder{number}` and files name as `files{number}.json` but in general they have different names.

In general I have 20 different sub-folders inside root folder and each sub-folder has around 30 files max.

**(figure 1)**

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   └── files3.json
├── folder2
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   └── files6.json
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.json
```

Now I am compressing all this into a `tar.gz` file by running below command -

```
tar cvzf ./products.tgz Products
```

**Question:-**

I got a new design as shown below where each sub-folder inside `Products` root folder has three environment folders in it - `dev`, `stage` and `prod`.

**(figure 2)**

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files1.json
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   ├── files3.json
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files1.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files1.json
├── folder2
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files5.json
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   ├── files6.json
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files5.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files5.json
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.json
```

For example - Inside `folder1` sub-folder there are three more sub-folders `dev`, `stage` and `prod` and exactly same thing for other sub-folders `folder2` and `folder3`. Each of those `dev`, `stage` and `prod` sub-folder inside `folder{number}` sub-folder will have files which are overridden for them.

I need to generate three different `tar.gz` file now - one for each `dev`, `stage` and `prod` from the above structure.

- Whatever files I have inside `dev`, `stage` and `prod` they will override their subfolder files if it is present in their sub-folder (folder1, folder2 or folder3) also.
- So if `files1.json` is present in `folder1` sub-folder and same file also present inside any of `dev`, `stage` and `prod` then while packaging I need to use whatever it is present in their environment folder and override their sub-folder files otherwise just use whatever is present in their sub-folder(s).

At the end I will have 3 different structures like this - one for `dev`, one for `stage` and other for `prod` where folder1 (or 2 and 3) will have files accordingly what I have in their environment as first preference since they are overridden and other files which are not overridden.

**(figure 3)**

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   └── files3.json
├── folder2
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   └── files6.json
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.json
```

And I need to generate `products-dev.gz`, `products-stage.gz` and `products-prod.gz` from the `figure 2` which will have data like `figure 3` but specific to each environment. Only difference is each sub-folder folder1 (2 or 3) will have files which are overridden for them as first preference from their particular environment folder and rest will use from their sub-folder only.

Is this possible to do through some linux commands? Only confusion I have is how to overwrite specific environment files inside particular sub-folder and then generate 3 different `tar.gz` file in them.

**Update:**

Also consider cases like the below:

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── files1.json
│   │   └── files5.json
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   ├── files3.json
│   ├── prod
│   │   ├── files10.json
│   │   └── files1.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files1.json
├── folder2
│   ├── dev
│   ├── prod
│   └── stage
└── folder3
    ├── dev
    ├── prod
    └── stage
```

As you can see `folder2` and `folder3` has environment overriding folders but they don't have any files so in that case I want to generate empty `folder2` and `folder3` as well in each environment specific `tar.gz` file.

Comment: Do you **have** to use that structure? Because it seems that having Production, Dev, Stage roots and then, inside each one the Product hierarchy you had up until now (with just the needed files) would make everything a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Yeah that can make things simpler but then I have to copy 3 different copies. Here I have a concept of default and overriden files for each environment. And also somehow my team wants this way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be plenty of ways, though all require some kind of complexity in order to handle the override case.

As a one-liner, though a bit long, you could do like this for one iteration i.e. one "environments" directory:

```bsh
(r=Products; e=stage; (find -- "$r" -regextype posix-extended -maxdepth 2 \( -regex '^[^/]+(/[^/]+)?' -o ! -type d \) -print0; find -- "$r" -mindepth 1 -path "$r/*/$e/*" -print0) | tar --null --no-recursion -czf "$r-$e.tgz" -T- --transform=s'%^\(\([^/]\{1,\}/\)\{2\}\)[^/]\{1,\}/%\1%')
```

broken down to observe it better:

```bsh
(
    r=Products; e=stage
    (
        find -- "$r" -regextype posix-extended -maxdepth 2 \( -regex '^[^/]+(/[^/]+)?' -o ! -type d \) -print0
        find -- "$r" -mindepth 1 -path "$r/*/$e/*" -print0
    ) \
        | tar --null --no-recursion -czf "$r-$e.tgz" -T- \
            --transform=s'%^\(\([^/]\{1,\}/\)\{2\}\)[^/]\{1,\}/%\1%'
)
```

Things to note:

1. it shows GNU tools' syntax. For BSD `find` you must replace `-regextype posix-extended` with just `-E` and for BSD `tar` you must replace `--no-recursion` with just `-n` as well as `--transform=s` (<- note the final `s`) with just `-s`
2. for simplicity of demonstration the snippet assumes to be run from the directory containing `Products`, and uses the custom `$e` variable for the name of the "environments" directory to archive, while `$r` is just a short-named helper variable to contain the `Products` name
3. it is enclosed within parentheses, making it a subshell, just so as not to pollute your shell with `$r` and `$e` should you run it from the command-line
4. it does not copy nor link/refer to the original files, it does handle any valid filename, it has no memory constraints, and it can handle any amount of names; the only assumption is about the first two levels of the directories hierarchy in that any directory directly below the first level is considered an "environments" directory and thus ignored (except the one indicated in `$e`)

You could simply enclose that snippet in a `for e in dev prod stage; do ...; done` shell loop and just go. (possibly taking away the outermost parentheses and rather surround the entire `for` loop).

The upside is that it is quite short and relatively simple after all.

The downside is that it always archives also **all** the *overridden* files (i.e. the base ones), the trick being just that the double `find` commands feed `tar` with the to-be-overridden files first, and hence during extraction they will be overwritten by the overriding files (i.e. the "environments" specific ones).  This leads to a bigger archive taking more time both during creation and during extraction, and might be undesirable depending on whether such "overhead" can be negligible or not.

That pipeline described in prose is:

0. (besides the outermost parentheses and the helper variables)
1. the first `find` command produces the list of non-specific files (and leading directories as per your update) only, while the second `find` produces the list of all environments-specific files only
2. the two `find` commands are within parentheses by themselves so that both their outputs feed the pipe to `tar` in sequence
3. `tar` reads such pipe in order to get the names of the files, and puts those files in the archive while also `--transform`-ing their names by eliminating the "environments" component (if present) from the path-name of each file
4. the two `find` commands are separated instead of being just one, and they are run one after the other, so that the non-specific files are produced (for `tar` to consume) before the environments-specific files, which enables the trick I described earlier

---

To avoid the overhead of including *always all* the files we need additional complexity in order to truly purge the overridden files. One way might be like below:

```bsh
# still a pipeline, but this time I won't even pretend it to be a one-liner

(
r=Products; e=stage; LC_ALL=C
find -- "$r" -regextype posix-extended \( -path "$r/*/$e/*" -o \( -regex '^([^/]+/){2}[^/]+' ! -type d \) -o -regex '^[^/]+(/[^/]+)?' \) -print0 \
    | sed -zE '\%^(([^/]+/){2})([^/]+/)%s%%0/\3\1%;t;s%^%1//%' \
    | sort -zt/ -k 3 -k 1,1n \
    | sort -zut/ -k 3 \
    | sed -zE 's%^[01]/(([^/]+/)|/)(([^/]+/?){2})%\3\2%' \
    | tar --null --no-recursion -czf "$r-$e.tgz" -T- \
        --transform=s'%^\(\([^/]\{1,\}/\)\{2\}\)[^/]\{1,\}/%\1%'
)
```

Several things to note:

1. everything we said earlier regarding GNU and BSD syntaxes for `find` and `tar` applies here as well
2. like the previous solution, it has no constraints whatsoever besides the assumption about the first two levels of the directories hierarchy
3. I'm using GNU `sed` here in order to deal with nul-delimited I/O (option `-z`), but you could easily replace those two `sed` commands with e.g. a `while read ...` shell loop (Bash version 3 or greater would be required) or another language you feel confident with, the only recommendation being that the tool you use is able to handle nul-delimited I/O (e.g. GNU's `gawk` can do it); see below for a replacement using Bash loops
4. I use one single `find` here, as I'm not relying on any implied behavior from `tar`
5. The `sed` commands manipulate the list of names, paving the way for the `sort` commands
6. specifically, the first `sed` moves the "environments" name at the beginning of the path, also prefixing it with a helper `0` number just to make it sort before the non-environments files, as I'm prefixing these latter with a leading `1` for the purpose of sorting
7. such preparation normalizes the list of names in the "eyes" of the `sort` commands, making all names without the "environments" name and all having the same amount of slash-delimited fields at the beginning, which is important for `sort`'s keys definitions
8. the first `sort` applies a sorting based first on the files' names, thus putting same names adjacent to each other, and then by numeric value of `0` or `1` as marked previously by the `sed` command, thus guaranteeing that any "environments" specific file, when present, comes before its non-specific counterpart
9. the second `sort` coalesces (option `-u`) on the files' names leaving only the first of duplicate names, which due to the previous reordering is always an "environments" specific file when present
10. finally, a second `sed` undoes what has been done by the first one, thus reshaping the file names for `tar` to archive

If you are curious to explore the intermediate pieces of such long pipeline, keep in mind that they all work with *nul*-delimited names, and hence do not show well on screen. You can pipe any one of the intermediate outputs (i.e. taking away at least the `tar`) to a courtesy `tr '\0' '\n'` to show a human-friendly output, just remember that filenames with newlines will span two lines on screen.

Several improvements could be done, certainly by making it a fully parameterized function/script, or for instance by detecting automatically any arbitrary name for "environments" directories, like below:

**Important**: pay attention to the comments as they may not be well accepted by an interactive shell

```
(
export r=Products LC_ALL=C
cd -- "$r/.." || exit
# make arguments out of all directories lying at the second level of the hierarchy
set -- "$r"/*/*/
# then expand all such paths found, take their basenames only, uniquify them, and pass them along xargs down to a Bash pipeline the same as above
printf %s\\0 "${@#*/*/}" \
    | sort -zu \
    | xargs -0I{} sh -c '
e="${1%/}"
echo --- "$e" ---
find -- "$r" -regextype posix-extended \( -path "$r/*/$e/*" -o \( -regex '\''^([^/]+/){2}[^/]+'\'' ! -type d \) -o -regex '\''^[^/]+(/[^/]+)?'\'' \) -print0 \
    | sed -zE '\''\%^(([^/]+/){2})([^/]+/)%s%%0/\3\1%;t;s%^%1//%'\'' \
    | sort -zt/ -k 3 -k 1,1n \
    | sort -zut/ -k 3 \
    | sed -zE '\''s%^[01]/(([^/]+/)|/)(([^/]+/?){2})%\3\2%'\'' \
    | tar --null --no-recursion -czf "$r-$e.tgz" -T- \
        --transform=s'\''%^\(\([^/]\{1,\}/\)\{2\}\)[^/]\{1,\}/%\1%'\''
' packetizer {}
)
```

---

Example replacement for the first `sed` command with a Bash loop:

```bsh
(IFS=/; while read -ra parts -d $'\0'; do
    if [ "${#parts[@]}" -gt 3 ]; then
        env="${parts[2]}"; unset parts[2]
        printf 0/%s/%s\\0 "$env" "${parts[*]}"
    else
        printf 1//%s\\0 "${parts[*]}"
    fi
done)
```

For the second `sed` command:

```bsh
(IFS=/; while read -ra parts -d $'\0'; do
    printf %s "${parts[*]:2:2}" "/${parts[1]:+${parts[1]}/}" "${parts[*]:4}"
    printf \\0
done)
```

Both snippets require the surrounding parentheses in order to be drop-in replacements for their respective `sed` commands within the pipeline above, and of course the `sh -c` piece after `xargs` needs to be turned into `bash -c`.

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunately there simply is no POSIX tool that can deal with nul-terminated input, neither can BSD's `awk` and `sed`. However I've now turned those shell loops into a couple of `sed -z` commands. Probably even more cryptic than before but at least more compact

Comment: @LL3 thanks it works fine now. One last question - Is there any way by which we can print total number of files count in each subfolder like `folder1`,  `folder2` and etc.? It doesn't need to be in same one liner script you had so I am ok doing it in separate line?

Comment: @cs98 In the extended pipeline there should be all the trickiest operations needed to let you count the names going into the archive. It may be a matter of inserting a `cut`/`sed` towards a final `uniq -c`. Try researching U&L about counting names as there are plenty of excellent answers on that very common task. Else it may make material for another good question. BTW: please consider upvoting and/or accepting answer(s) you found useful, it is a "concrete" way to say thank you and gives first glance hints to future readers having similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

#### General solution

1. Make a copy of the directory tree. Hardlink the files to save space.
2. Modify the copy. (In case of hardlinks, you need to know what you can do safely. See below.)
3. Archive the copy.
4. Remove the copy.
5. Repeat (modifying differently) if needed.

---

#### Example

Limitations:

- this example uses non-POSIX options (tested on Debian 10),
- it makes some assumptions about the directory tree,
- it can fail if there are too many files.

Treat it as a proof of concept, adjust it to your needs.

1. Making a copy

   `cd` to the parent directory of `Products`. This directory, `Products` and everything within should belong to a single filesystem. Make a temporary directory and recreate `Products` there:

   ```
   mkdir -p tmp
   cp -la Products/ tmp/
   ```
2. Modifying the copy

   Files in the two directory trees are hardlinked. If you modify their *content* then you will alter the original data. Operations that modify information held by directories are safe, they will not alter the original data if performed in the other tree. These are:

   - removing files,
   - renaming files,
   - moving files around (this includes moving a file over another file with `mv`),
   - creating totally independent files.

   In your case for every directory named `dev` at the right depth move its contents one level up:

   ```
   cd tmp/Products
   dname=dev
   find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "$dname" -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && mv -f -- * ../' sh {} \;
   ```

   Notes:

   - `mv -- * ../` is prone to `argument list too long`,
   - by default `*` does not match dotfiles.

   Then remove directories:

   ```
   find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
   ```

   Note this removes the now empty `dev` and unneeded `prod`, `stage`; *and* any other directory at this depth.
3. Archiving the copy

   ```
   # still in tmp/Products because of the previous step
   cd ..
   tar cvzf "products-$dname.tgz" Products
   ```
4. Removing the copy

   ```
   # now in tmp because of the previous step
   rm -rf Products
   ```
5. Repeating

   Go back to the right directory and start over, this time with `dname=stage`; and so on.

---

#### Example script (quick and dirty)

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=Products
[ -d "$dir" ] || exit 1
mkdir -p tmp

for dname in dev prod stage; do
(
   cp -la "$dir" tmp/
   cd "tmp/$dir"
   [ "$?" -eq 0 ] || exit 1
   find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "$dname" -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && mv -f -- * ../' sh {} \;
   find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
   cd ..
   [ "$?" -eq 0 ] || exit 1
   tar cvzf "${dir,,}-$dname.tgz" "$dir"
   rm -rf "$dir" || exit 1
) || exit "$?"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I made that bit more generic and working on non-trivial file names without actually changing the source directories

`Products` is given as argument. keywords `dev prod stage` are hard-coded inside script (but can easily changed)

**Note: this is GNU specific `--transform` and `-print0` `-z` extension**

run the script
`./script Products`

```
#!/bin/sh

# environment
subdirs="dev prod stage"

# script requires arguments
[ -n "$1" ] || exit 1

# remove trailing /
while [ ${i:-0} -le $# ]
  do
    i=$((i+1))
    dir="$1"
    while [ "${dir#"${dir%?}"}" = "/" ]
      do
        dir="${dir%/}"
    done
    set -- "$@" "$dir"
    shift
done

# search string
for sub in $subdirs
  do
    [ -n "$search" ] && search="$search -o -name $sub" || search="( -name $sub"
done
search="$search )"

# GNU specific zero terminated handling for non-trivial directory names
excludes="$excludes $(find -L "$@" -type d $search -print0 | sed -z 's,[^/]*/,*/,g' | sort -z | uniq -z | xargs -0 printf '--exclude=%s\n')"

# for each argument
for dir in "$@"
  do
    # for each environment
    [ -e "$dir" ] || continue
    for sub in $subdirs
      do
        # exclude other subdirs
        exclude=$(echo "$excludes" | grep -v "$sub")

#        # exclude files that exist in subdir (at least stable against newlines and spaces in file names)
#        include=$(echo "$excludes" | grep "$sub" | cut -d= -f2)
#        [ -n "$include" ] && files=$(find $include -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | tr '\n[[:space:]]' '?' | sed -z "s,/$sub/,/," | xargs -0 printf '--exclude=%s\n')
#        exclude="$exclude $files"

        # create tarball archive
        archive="${dir##*/}-${sub}.tgz"
        [ -f "$archive" ] && echo "WARNING: '$archive' is overwritten"
        tar --transform "s,/$sub$,," --transform "s,/$sub/,/," $exclude -czhf "$archive" "$dir"
    done
done
```

You might notice duplicates inside archive. `tar` will recursively descend directories, on restore the deeper files will **overwrite** files on parent directory

However, that needs some more testing against consistent behavior (not sure about that). the proper way would be exlude `files1.json` + `files5.json` unfortunately `-X` doesn't work with `--null`

if you don't trust that behavior or don't want duplicate files in archives you can add some exclude for simple file names. **uncomment** the code above `tar`. newlines and whitespaces allowed in file names but will be excluded with wildcard `?` in exclude pattern, which could in theory exclude more files than expected (if there are similar files matching that pattern)

you can place a `echo` before `tar` and you will see the script generates the following commands

```
tar --transform 's,/dev$,,' --transform 's,/dev/,/,' --exclude=*/*/prod --exclude=*/*/stage -czhf Products-dev.tgz Products
tar --transform 's,/prod$,,' --transform 's,/prod/,/,' --exclude=*/*/dev --exclude=*/*/stage -czhf Products-prod.tgz Products
tar --transform 's,/stage$,,' --transform 's,/stage/,/,' --exclude=*/*/dev --exclude=*/*/prod -czhf Products-stage.tgz Products
```

Comment: if you uncomment the *exclude files* block you might get *Argument list too long* for too many files. pass excludes via `-X` index file in that case